# Mongoose- How can I create a collection with the default values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am creating a schema with the following code;

```
var Repository = require('./base/Repository'); 
var Connection = require('./base/Connection');

    var scm = Repository.schema({
        userId : String,
        text: String,
        date: Number });

    scm.index({date:1}); scm.index({userId:1});

    var repo = Repository.create('Feedback', scm, Connection);

    module.exports = new repo();
```

But I want to give default values for the fields while creating this schema.   For example I want something like that ;

```
var scm = Repository.schema({
        userId : 12334455,
        text: hello world,
        date: 19.04.2018 });
```

How can I manage this with  Mongoose ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html

you may wish to use the `setDefaultsOnInsert` option.

Comment: You'll have to edit your schema for this to work, but I upvoted because this is what I was looking for.

Comment: you make a good life choices

Answer (score 1):

You can always specify default values while defining your schema. Like

```
Repository.schema({
userId : { type: String, default: '12334455' },
text: { type: String, default: 'Xyx' },
date: { type: String, default: 12334455 }
})
```

Here is [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my schema according to your answer.But there is no  document in my collection.I am waiting a document that contains  userid=1234 text=yyyyy. What can be the prolem ?

Comment: While creating schema I am using the following code ; var repo = Repository.create('Feedback', scm, Connection);  How can I force to create document with default values

Comment: you didn't read the documentation probably. Please have a look at it here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html